# How do I parse an exact count of a certain character in Chumsky?

Tags: parsing, rust

How can I use [chumsky](https://docs.rs/chumsky/latest/chumsky/) to get the three binary characters from a binary string? I can't figure out from the documentation how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I see now it's possible to use `Repeated::exactly` like this:

```
let digits = one_of::<_, _, Cheap<char>>("01")
    .repeated().exactly(3)
    .then_ignore(end())
    .collect::<String>();
```